# when trying to connect to computers in office is says wrong password , but pass works on local machine

Tags: networking, passwords

I'm my office network, I'm using all deferent types of windows from xp to 10 
the problem I have is from these 2 computers one is running win 8.1 enterprise one is running win 10 pro .
from all other computer I can connect to either of them , but these 2 cant connect to each other .
when I try to reach it from network ploace or by \192.168.1.10 or \london-pc it will prompt for credential and when I put that in it says its incorrect 
using net use it says network specified password is incorrect 
but password works on local machines ,
in network and sharing centre advance sharing , all setting are set to be able to access with least secure way so, there shouldn't be any restrictions. 
my other win 10 pro can connect to it without any problem , I checked all settings and they look the same  .,,- more info : I have dhcp on my main router and about 5 or 6 smart switch(unmanaged)

Comment: What users are listed in the permissions on the file shares you are trying to access?   Are the shared folders locked down to to particular users?   Have you tried to share the folder in question with the 'Everyone' user allowed to read the folder over the network?   Are you on a Windows Domain (Active Directory)?